# Check my design of database tables for SQLite

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I'm making a trivia game and I was wondering if this approach was OK?

```
trivia_table
    *movie_id
    name
    genre
question_table
    *movie_id
    *question_id
    question
    difficulty
answers_table
    *question_id
    A
    B
    C
    D
    Answer
```

So each movie will have its own table of questions.

I also thought that maybe I could throw all my questions in one big table and by adding the number of questions there are for each movie in the question_table and then adding the pk movie_id to the answers_table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine the question and answer tables - you will have one answer row for each question. A single question won't have multiple answer rows.  A single answer won't apply to multiple questions.

You should not have separate tables for each movie (or a separate table for each movie as revised).

If the question ID is unique (across all movies), you can make it the primary key of the combined Q&A table.

Your 'trivia_table' would be better named 'movies'.  Your combined Q&A table could be called 'trivia'.  There is no virtue in the `_table` suffix on the table name.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: It's working well. i'm selecting the question based on the movie_id and question_id.